# Get trace file name from TextWriterTraceListener?

Tags: c#, .net, trace, system.diagnostics, tracelistener

I'm using `TextWriterTraceListener` in my application, if file is not available to write trace, it create another trace file with GUID prefix.

All I'm interested is to get the trace file name. In normal condition, I know what would be the filename, but when `TextWriterTraceListener` prefixes the GUID, how do I predict/get the trace file name?

Answer (score 0):

`TextWriterTraceListener` has a `Name` property, isn't it what you are looking for?

**EDIT**
I tried to access the information you need but without success, mainly because the `SystemDiagnosticsSection` class that contains the app.config informations is inaccessible. I think your only chance is to parse the XML of the app.config or to use reflections to access some inner field of the object (which I'd not recommend).

Comment: No really! It is kind of identifier for Trace. To be more specific I'm looking for `initializeData` (Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1ckdta4(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think TextWriterTraceListener has a private method called fileName. I used the debugger's immediate window to  test the following:

```
l.Name;
"textFileListener"
l.fileName;
"C:\\Tools\\Support\\PatchInstaller\\bin\\Debug\\trace.txt"
```

I can't find a way to access that private method fileName. I tried inherit from TextWriterTraceListener but could not see that method. The only way so far is to use the Debugger.

Check out [using .Writer property in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769772/reading-tracelistener-initializedata-property-from-config-net-1-1).